# Sound Problems with my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, audio

Today I dropped some juice on my iPhone 4 and since the iPhone's keyboard and others tones aren't working. The calling tone works however.

I keep getting the following message:

> This accessory is not optimized for this phone! You may experice noise caused by cellular interference and a decrease in cellular signal strength

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My girlfriend dropped her iPhone 4 in a glass of coke (it submerged completely). Afterwards, she experienced the same symptoms as you. To fix it, she put the phone in a bowl of rice, and took a blow dryer to it once or twice a day. I believe she also got some electrical contact cleaner and cleaned the connection on the bottom that you plug the USB cable into.

It took about a week, but the phone worked perfectly afterwards (and has been working perfectly ever since).